# Mandatory or optional updates for code push based on release

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I'm using code push plugin to push updates on my app without passing through the play store.

I think is a great utility to have this. Reviewing the documentation from the App Center, I see that you may make an update to be mandatory or optional, for which the user may ignore it. The configuration for doing this happens from within the app itself, inside the code.

I was wondering if there's a way to make some updates mandatory and some others optional, based on the codepush release you are doing.

I saw that when you run this command to trigger a new update you need to specify your user+app, the path to the source where the built app is with the require changes, the target version(s) where this update will be prompted to be installed, the environment and a description... But I don't see the possibility to send extra parameters to indicate if it would be mandatory to install it or not, and based on this when checking for updates inside the app, configure dynamically the notification for the user.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `--mandatory true` flag, as in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/cli